# Scaling a distribution in JAGS

Tags: jags

If I have the following model `y~s*dist(a,b)` where `s` is a constant and `dist` is a given distribution (assume that the parameters `a` and `b` cannot be transformed to account for scaling), how do I model this in JAGS?

I get the following error: **"[...] is a logical node and cannot be observed"** simply trying the above description.

**EDIT:**

I am trying to estimate the parameters of a CIR process (it has a scaled non-central chi square distribution, cf [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIR_process) )

```
model {
    for (i in 2:length(timeSerie)){
        ncp[i] <- c*et*timeSerie[i-1]
        timeSerie[i] ~ dnchisqr(df,ncp[i])/c
    }

    #parameters
    et <- exp(-kappa*timeStep)
    c <- 4*kappa/(sigma^2*(1-et))
    df <- 4*kappa*mu/sigma^2

    #CIR parameter priors 
    lkappa ~ dunif(-10,-2)
    kappa <- exp(lkappa)
    mu ~ dunif(3,10)
    lsigma ~ dunif(0,5) 
    sigma <- exp(lsigma)
}
```

Comment: could you pls also provide the code?

Comment: @suncoolsu please see 'EDIT'

Comment: I am assuming the `ncp` is the given data? did you use a `data{}` snippet before `model{}` snippet?

Comment: @suncoolsu `ncp` is a function of the parameters (kappa and sigma, through c). No I have not used the the `data` snippet.

Comment: how do you get your data? JAGS or any other Gibbs sampler will give posterior distributions based on the given data. Are you saying this is your complete code? If yes, then I don't see the point of using JAGS.

Comment: @suncoolsu my data is a simulated CIR process path in the `timeSerie` variable. Actually I have 2 inputs: `timeSerie` and `timeStep`. I am running **JAGS** with `rjags`, so the data is created in **R**.

Comment: Ok -- so your model formulation in JAGS is not right. I will give an answer later in the day when I am bit free.